# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'constant'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
@objc  func handleKeyboardDidShow (notification: NSNotification)
{
    let keyboardRectAsObject = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    var keyboardRect = CGRect.zero

    keyboardRectAsObject.getValue(&keyboardRect)

    self.changePassView.constant = -1 * keyboardRect.height/2

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
}
```

Can anyone help me? Why I am getting this error as I am a beginner to iOS and learning this language.

Comment: You should modify a `NSLayoutConstraint` object, which does have a property named `constant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `self.changePassView.constant = -1 * keyboardRect.height/2`

You're getting the error because you're trying to access a property called `constant` in `self.changePassView`, which is apparently a `UIView`. It looks like you're trying to change the value of the view's bottom constraint, but a layout constraint is a separate object that you'll have to get before you can set it's value. This might help: [How to get constraint "bottomSpace" from UIView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29348661/643383)

Answer (score 0):

`UIViews` contain information about their own appearance and content.

`NSLayoutConstraints` are often added to UIViews to modify how they're distributed across the screen.

You're receiving an error because you're attempting to access a property, `constant`, that is not found in `UIViews`. You're close though. You need a `NSLayoutConstraint.`

**Step 1: Set Constraints**

You can do this programmatically ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift)) or with the help of storyboards / nibs. Here's a step-by-step for the storyboard/nib approach:

1. Add a constraint in your storyboard or nib with auto layout.
2. Create an `NSLayoutConstraint` variable in your UIView class.
3. Back in your storyboard, find your newly-created constraint. It'll show up in your view navigator on the left, next to your `UIView`.
4. Select the constraint your looking for, and navigate to the rightmost tab of Xcode's right-hand panel.
5. Drag a "New Referencing Outlet" from the right panel to your `UIViewController` class in your view navigator.
6. If done correctly, an option for your new `NSLayoutConstraint` will appear. Select it.

Now the variable in your code is references the constraint you made visually. If these steps are confusing and you're very much a beginner (I can't quite tell) please reference [this thorough guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5055364-ios-storyboards-getting-started) to storyboards.

**Step 2: Putting it Together**

Access your `NSLayoutConstraint`'s `constant` value. Your code should look like something like this once all of the above steps are complete:

```
// In your class's definitions.
// This is what you'll have to link programmatically or in your storyboard/nib
@IBOutlet var changePassViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// Later on in your function:
self.changePassViewBottomConstraint.constant = -1 * keyboardRect.height/2
```